How can I access Instagram posts or reels sent by users to a chatbot's DM?
I'm building a chatbot for Instagram and initially used Chatfuel to set it up. When users send an Instagram post or reel to the chatbot’s direct messages (DMs), Chatfuel can't access or view the content of the post or reel. I tried using other bot providers, including Chatbot.com, ManyChat, and SendPulse, but none of them could access posts or reels either.
Is there any way to access or interact with posts or reels sent by users to a chatbot's DM on Instagram? I would appreciate any workarounds, APIs, or a code-based solution if available. I’m open to building the bot with code if that allows for more direct access.
What I Tried:
I initially tried using Chatfuel to create the chatbot, hoping it would be able to access posts or reels shared by users in the chatbot's DMs. However, Chatfuel could not retrieve or display these media links. I then experimented with other chatbot providers, including Chatbot.com, ManyChat, and SendPulse, expecting at least one of them to support this functionality. Unfortunately, none of these platforms could access or interact with Instagram posts or reels shared in DMs either.
Expected Outcome:
I expected that when a user sent an Instagram post or reel to the chatbot’s DM, the chatbot would be able to access the link for further processing.
Actual Result:
None of the platforms I tried could access the posts or reels, and the chatbot was unable to respond or interact with these types of messages in the way I needed.
